# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clx'

Tags: docker, rapids

I am attempting to run the first cell in Jupyter notebook: /rapids/notebooks/clx/alert_analysis/Alert_Analysis_with_CLX.ipynb, which results in following error:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clx'*

From an IPython shell running on the Rapids container, I do "import clx", then doing dir(clx) shows following:

```
In [2]: import clx

In [3]: dir(clx)
Out[3]: 
['__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__']

In [4]:
```

I must be missing something simple, but it escapes me at the moment what is wrong here... can anybody advise what I am forgetting, or doing wrong?

Thanks,

p.s. - am following this procedure: https://rapids.ai/start.html  The container is up and running with:  Digest hash:

```
sha256:774ca3d612de15213102c2dbbba55df44dc5cf9870ca2be6c6e9c627fa63d67a
```

The container run invocation was:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm -it -p 8888:8888 -p 8787:8787 -p 8786:8786     rapidsai/rapidsai-core-dev:21.06-cuda11.2-devel-ubuntu20.04-py3.8
```

Comment: clx may not be included in the default RAPIDS container. You can likely install it following the [installation steps](https://github.com/rapidsai/clx#installation) on the Github repository.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense, and will start looking into that next

Answer (score 0):

As Nick Becker said, you need to run, CLX is not installed in the RAPIDS containers by default.  However, you can quickly install it into your container by running this command in terminal inside of your container:
`conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c pytorch -c conda-forge clx`

Comment: Hello - Yes, thanks again for the help getting through that part, as I was able to get the conda install approach you describe to work.  I am now able to get through cell 1 of the notebook, but have a follow-up question, as I am getting stopped by the s3 datasource not being available anymore:

```
fs.get("rapidsai-data/cyber/clx/splunk_faker_raw4", "./splunk_faker_raw4")
```
returns
PermissionError: Access Denied
I can understand the public s3 not being available forever, is a set of example data available, otherwise, or how can I proceed through the example?
Thanks!